# datepicker calendar disappears when scrolling on mobile/tablet

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker, calendar

datepicker calendar disappears when scrolling on mobile/tablet.

When i click the field (on mobile or tablet) Date , the calender appears but when i want to scroll ( you have to touch the screen to scroll) the calendar dissapears. It's very annoying, because that's the last thing i need to get it working.

You can view the date field below:
http://domburghome.com/domburg/index.php/hotel/jan-tooropstraat-2a/

please can somebody help me. thnxx

Comment: I am not able to replicate that behaviour on my devices.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but was in the top results when I was searching for solutions, so here's how I fixed it.  If you are using the Bootstrap datepicker, check for the mousedown event handler and see if it is also bound to touchstart.  Simply remove the touchstart.

```
$(document), {
                'mousedown touchstart': $.proxy(function(e){
```

change this to

```
$(document), {
                'mousedown': $.proxy(function(e){
```

Commit is here: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/pull/1284